Can I use an immovable object to create an airship?
I have read a few questions about immovable objects, specifically ones about immovable rod ladders and flight. I believe that you could suspend a ship in the air, but the problem is movement.
There is much debate around this phrase from the spell immovable object:

can move the object normally

and what that would mean. Does it mean that I could slide the object across a plane by simply pushing it in a specific direction, or would it mean that as soon as I want to move it, gravity would set in?

@TreeSpawned the spell immovable object: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dnd/egtw/character-options-subclasses#ImmovableObject

Is your question about the spell immovable Object, the Magic Item the Immovable Rod or both? I didn't know that spell existed (thanks for @Thomas Markov for helping me out here), so I edited your question to be about the Magic item in particular, if I made a mistake here, please revert these changes.

I see that this question has been much improved and more focused. But now the title and the text ask two different questions. Which one should be answered?

I think it's important to remember several things: -

Firstly, The Explorer's Guide to Wildemount is partnered content, so it may not be considered appropriate source material at your table. It's also worth noting that while Critical Role content is often fun and imaginative, it's sometimes written with less stringent specificity than official 5e content.
Secondly, since this question is tagged "dnd-5e-2024", it might be relevant that this sourcebook came out several years before the current edition, so this is another reason it may be discounted by your DM.
Thirdly, like Thomas addresses in his answer, the description of the spell describes an object being "magically fixed in place", except it can be "moved normally" by the caster and designated creatures when the spell is cast.

I think this is intended (as much as we can ever infer such things) to be moved in-person, at relatively small distances, supressing the stuck-in-place magic while being manipulated, allowing it to be used to, for example, selectively lock a doorway but allow your friends to pass, or create an anchor point that characters can use to climb, but move when they are finished with it. I agree with Thomas that  you would still need to be able to actually move the object either physically or with appropriate magic that can affect the total weight.
However, a very liberal and literal interpretation of "moved normally" could arguably include things like Mage Hand or Catapult spells, as well as other methods of remote movement (ropes, motors, etc.) which could be used to move the object. I think it would be a stretch to find a DM willing to allow such remote movement to overcome the immobility, but if they did you would be in the realms of speculating weights and bearing loads of materials as discussed in some of the other answers. (I had previously mentioned the Telekinesis spell, but then realised that with its higher weight limit, it would be a much easier, albeit higher level, way of moving e.g. a small boat, than Immovable Object).
Ultimately, this is likely to come down to how your DM chooses to interpret this slightly vague spell description, and the flavour of game they run. It's not 100% clear whether you are intending to do this in a game, but if you want to design and create a flying ship of some kind, I would suggest working with your DM to see how that would be possible, and maybe bring up your Immovable Object spell ideas as part of a collaborative homebrew process to make something fun.

EGtW is “official” in that it is published by WotC as a D&D product. There are other materials published by WotC that are not published as official D&D products, such as the Planescape materials, but there’s no doubt EGtW is official content. It isn’t AL legal, but it’s definitely official.

Do you think I should amend "official" to "usable" or possibly describe it as "optional content"?
It's in "Partnered Content" on D&D Beyond, for example, along with "Dungeons and Dragons VS Rick and Morty" and the Kobold Press "Tome of Beasts", for example. The recent Planescape releases are in "Sourcebooks" - this is what I was basing my description off.

Your point about it being a likely candidate for being forbidden is the important observation, and is similar to my experience.

I've edited it to "may not be considered appropriate source material" in an effort to be less confusing.

A real ship is not a valid target for immovable object, so no
The immovable object spell says:

You touch an object that weighs no more than 10 pounds and cause it to become magically fixed in place. You and the creatures you designate when you cast this spell can move the object normally. (...)
If the object is fixed in the air, it can hold up to 4,000 pounds of weight. More weight causes the object to fall.

A ship is a large vessel, sturdy enough to transport people and goods by sea. An actual ship has a weight of several tons and cannot be fixed in the air with this spell that has a 10-pound limit. Even a simple rowboat weighs 100 lbs, 10 times what this spell can handle, and is illegal.
For supporting a ship heavier than 10 pounds, you could make a number of pegs or rods stick in the air that together prod up a ship if their combined bearing capacity of 4,000 pounds each would support its weight. But in that case, the ship's weight is unchanged, and while you could move the rods higher if there is nothing in the way, you won't be able to do so with the weight of thousands of pounds of ship pressing down on them. So you won't even be able to lift the ship from the ground this way.
It wouldn't even work if it was a legal target
If you're are talking about something lightweight, like a folding boat (that is a valid target, as it weighs less than 10 lbs), being able to move it normally will not give you the ability to move it in any other way than as you normally would be able to, without the spell. That means you could maybe lift it up from the floor, but unless you have a fly speed that allows you to do so, you will not be able to move it around in midair, when you have no leverage point to push against, just as you could not if there was no spell on it.
Think about it this way: if the only reason you are able to hang in air is because you are propped up on an object that you made stick there with immovable object, either you do not try to move it around, and can thus lean on it or hang from it, or you opt to move it normally - but when you do and "unstick" it, there is nothing holding you up anymore, and you would drop, along with the normally moving object.

PS. It was pointed out that an earlier version of this question assumed you would make every single piece of wood of the ship into an immovable object and put the ship together from those. Even a light ship, like a Viking longship weighed over four metric tons, or nearly 9,000 pounds. You would need enough casters and time to cast 900 instances of this spell, making this entirely impractical for play, other than as a thought exercise (and you‘d need to cast it at 6th spell level or higher so it doesn't end until dispelled) And even then you could not move it around to pseudo-fly, as explained above.

The longer version of the question that was edited out discussed a ship of Theseus type situation where you manufacture the ship out of immovable objects.

@ThomasMarkov Thanks, I missed that. That‘d be entirely impractical too - it would need hundreds or thousands of castings of this 1-hour duration spell and building a ship takes a long time. By the time you would have them all assembled, the magic would be long gone.

@NobodytheHobgoblin The duration is longer and even permanent if cast with a higher spell slot, so the Ship of Theseus is feasible with sufficient down-time.

@nonymous Ah thanks, that‘s a good point. I removed the section about time being a limit. And I guess given long downtime of a few years, even a single wizard casting it at 6th level or higher could get there, volume wise.

@NobodytheHobgoblin, You wouldn't even need to cast it on every piece of the ship, just load-bearing structures. Theoretically, the 20,000 weight limit would even be increased with multiple castings. However, it does occur to me that the whole structure would be immobile, except for the particular pieces that a designated creature moves. So, ship of Theseus wouldn't work.

A mundane ship flying through the air is not “moving normally”.
The immovable object spell stipulates that you can move the object normally. It’s really important that we understand what this means: anything you could do to the object before casting the spell, you can do after casting the spell. The spell doesn’t change how you are able to move the object, and this works both ways: it neither restricts, nor enhances, your ability to move the object. You can continue to move the object normally. Therefore, you cannot make a ship fly that could not normally fly.
So even if you could get the spell applied to the whole ship, which is dubious at best, you can’t move it through the air.

Yes, the right object can be converted to an "airship" in this way.
The target object must be no more than 10 lbs:

... an object that weighs no more than 10 pounds

so you might need to cast the spell on something light enough, like a folding boat (4 lbs), in order to stay under the weight limit. The clause

…the creatures you designate when you cast this spell can move the object normally.

clearly means that the "designated creatures" can bypass the spell’s restriction on movement. It does not impose additional restrictions on the type of movement, as others seem to suggest.
Immovable Object has a duration of 1 hour (longer if cast using a 4th-level or higher spell slot), unless dispelled. In other words, if a "designated creature" moves the object, the spell does not end. Therefore, it is possible to move the object without causing it to fall from suspension.
Theoretically, if you designate a flying creature, that creature could push the suspended object, effectively creating an “airship” with weight limits of up to 4,000 lbs. at 2nd level, 8,000 lbs. at 4th or 5th level, and 20,000 lbs. at higher levels.

If the object is fixed in the air, it can hold up to 4,000 pounds of weight.


At Higher Levels: If you cast this spell using a 4th or 5th-level spell slot, the DC to move the object increases by 5, it can carry up to 8,000 pounds, and the duration increases to 24 hours. If you cast this spell using a 6th-level or higher spell slot, the DC to move the object increases by 10, it can carry up to 20,000 pounds, and the effect is permanent until dispelled.

Any designated creature with a flying speed could then push the object horizontally using the following guidelines for amount of necessary force.

If you wanted to figure out how hard it would be to move a 4000 lb object through the air, here is a real world comparison:
Step 1: Convert weight to mass (in kilograms)
You gave the weight of the object as 4000 lbs. Since 1 lb (pound-force) is equal to approximately 4.44822 N (Newtons), we can first convert pounds to Newtons, and then use the acceleration due to gravity to find the mass.
Force due to gravity (Weight in Newtons)
$$
4000 \, \text{lbs} \times 4.44822 \, \frac{\text{N}}{\text{lb}} = 17,792.88 \, \text{N}
$$
Mass (in kilograms)
The acceleration due to gravity, ( g ), is approximately 9.81 m/s². To find the mass, we use the equation:
$$
\text{Mass (kg)} = \frac{\text{Weight (N)}}{g}
$$
$$
\text{Mass} = \frac{17,792.88 \, \text{N}}{9.81 \, \text{m/s}^2} = 1814.39 \, \text{kg}
$$
Step 2: Convert speed (4 mph) to meters per second (m/s)
To convert 4 mph to m/s, we multiply by the conversion factor ( 1 mph = 0.44704, m/s):
$$
4 \, \text{mph} \times 0.44704 \, \frac{\text{m/s}}{\text{mph}} = 1.788 \, \text{m/s}
$$
Step 3: Calculate acceleration (in meters per second squared, m/s²)
To find the acceleration required to go from rest (0 m/s) to 1.788 m/s in 30 seconds, we use the equation for acceleration:
$$
a = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}
$$
where:
$$( \Delta v = v_f - v_0 = 1.788 \, \text{m/s} - 0 \, \text{m/s} = 1.788 \, \text{m/s} )$$
$$( \Delta t = 30 \, \text{s} )$$
$$
a = \frac{1.788 \, \text{m/s}}{30 \, \text{s}} = 0.0596 \, \text{m/s}^2
$$
Step 4: Calculate the force (in Newtons)
Now, we can calculate the force using Newton’s second law:
$$
F = m \cdot a
$$
Where:
$$( m = 1814.39 \, \text{kg} )$$
$$( a = 0.0596 \, \text{m/s}^2 )$$
$$
F = 1814.39 \, \text{kg} \times 0.0596 \, \text{m/s}^2 = 108.20 \, \text{N}
$$
Step 5: Convert the force to pounds-force (lbf)
To convert from Newtons to pounds-force, use the conversion factor:
$$
1 \, \text{lbf} = 4.44822 \, \text{N}
$$
$$
F = \frac{108.20 \, \text{N}}{4.44822 \, \frac{\text{N}}{\text{lbf}}} = 24.3 \, \text{lbf}
$$
Summary of Results:

The force required to accelerate a 4000 lb object from rest to 4 mph in 30 seconds is approximately 108.2 N or 24.3 lbf.


Comparison:
108.2 N or 24.3 lbf is the equivalent of...
1. A Light Grocery Bag
A typical plastic or paper grocery bag with a few items weighs roughly 2–3 pounds. So, the force required to accelerate the 4000 lb object at that rate is about the same as lifting a light grocery bag.
2. Force of a Light Push
Think about the force you apply when you push a car that’s already rolling slowly, or when you gently push a large, empty shopping cart. The amount of force to accelerate an object from rest to 4 mph over 30 seconds would be a light push in this scenario.
3. A Human Hand Push
Imagine using your hand to push against a small desk or chair. This amount of force (around 2.43 lbf) is similar to a firm push that a person might apply to move something lightweight across a smooth surface.
4. Typical Small Appliance
A small kitchen appliance, like a toaster or blender, typically weighs around 2 to 4 pounds. The force to move a 4000 lb object to 4 mph over 30 seconds is roughly the same as the weight of such a small appliance.
5. One-Third the Force of Gravity on a 10-lb Object
Gravity exerts a downward force on any object, and on a 10-lb object, it pulls with a force of 10 lbf. To accelerate that object at the same rate (4 mph in 30 seconds), you'd need about one-third of that force—around 3 lbf.
Summary:
So, 2.43 lbf is a relatively small force that could be compared to lifting or pushing a light object like a grocery bag, a small appliance, or giving a gentle push to something that rolls easily. It’s not a huge amount of force in everyday terms, but remember that it’s being applied continuously over 30 seconds to gradually reach 4 mph, which adds up to an interesting movement when scaled to a large object.

Unfortunately, I don't think this is correct. I have no idea about all the maths and equations, but a folding boat only weighs 4lbs when it's folded up into a box. The item description reads "When the box becomes a vessel, its weight becomes that of a normal vessel its size". A rowboat, for example, weighs 100lbs.

The Folding Boat is just an example, it could be any object that it light enough. However, technically, the object only needs to be less than 10 lbs at the time of casting, so the Folding Boat actually does work. DM fiat could adjudicate whether the change in weight interrupts the spell or counts towards the load maximum.

Yeah, that's a valid interpretation.
I suspect there are rather more simple ways to obtain flight than the querent's scheme, but well done for taking a crack at it!

This answer is precluded by the general 2024 rule that D&D is not a physics simulation.

That doesn’t preclude the answer. You can ignore the math, it’s just a suggestion about how hard it would be for a creature to push the object.
